# Regex Whitespace to Anchor (\s*$) Consumes Line Feed

Tags: regex, perl

By default, the end-of-line anchor is supposed to occupy the imaginary position between the last character and the line feed.
Why does '\s*$' consume the line feed in the following example?

```
perl -pe 's/(\.\d{4})\d+\s*$/\1/'
```

The objective of the above substitution is to truncate digit.5+digits to digit.4digits
e.g.:  `123.54321 -> 123.5432`

I don't want to waste time transforming ".5+digits non-digits" (e.g.:  5.12345 blah) because it will just fail pre-load validation anyway.

```
/home/mlibby> echo -e '38492.38945\n5.12345 blah\n624.54321  \n9.325437' | perl -pe 's/(\.\d{4})\d+$/\1/'
38492.3894
5.12345 blah
624.54321
9.3254
```

However, I *do* want to transform ".5+digits whitespace" (e.g.:  624.54321   ) because trailing whitespace is valid, but should be trimmed.
So after I consume 5th-to-many digits, I say `\s*$` consume zero-or-more whitespace up to the end-of-subject anchor.

```
/home/mlibby> echo -e '38492.38945\n5.12345 blah\n624.54321  \n9.325437' | perl -pe 's/(\.\d{4})\d+\s*$/\1/'
38492.38945.12345 blah
624.54329.3254/home/mlibby>
```

So, why is the above search pattern consuming the line feed, causing the substitution to remove LF and ultimately truncate lines?

Granted, I can change my substitution to `\1\n`, but the point of this post is to *understand* what's going on here.  By default, `$` should anchor west of the line feed.  What's going on here?

FYI:  Perl version 5.8.8 on RHEL 5.8

Answer (score 3):

`$` matches in *either* of two places: at the end of the string, or immediately before a newline at the end of the string.

A newline is a kind of whitespace, so `\s` matches it. So your `\s*` consumes any trailing whitespace *including* the newline, and since `$` matches at end of string even if there's not a newline, no backtrack is forced.

You could use a non-greedy match `\s*?` to match as little whitespace as possible, thus guaranteeing that it won't eat up the newline that `$` is prepared to ignore.

Or you could match any whitespace that isn't a newline, namely `[^\S\n]` (if that seems weird, think about De Morgan's law — NOT ((NOT whitespace) OR newline) == whitespace AND (NOT newline)

Comment: Bingo!  Lazy quantifier worked like a charm.  I thought `$` always preceded the final newline, so in multi-line mode it would be end-of-string, but if in single line mode, it would anchor ahead (west of) the LF.  Thank you.  This was helpful.

Comment: Re "thus guaranteeing that it won't eat up the newline", non-greediness normally makes no such guarantees; it's so frequently misused! It'll will in this very specific case, though. As such, it's a very good practice to avoid except as an optimisation

Answer (score 0):

`\s` matches newlines and `$` matches end of input (after the very last character)

Change you regex to match only non-newline whitespace (eg spaces and tabs):

```
perl -pe 's/(\.\d{4})\d+[ \t]*$/\1/'
```